# Move Symfony2 project to dev server from localhost

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, ubuntu, apache2

guys. I know that post not fully related to programming. But I really need someone help. So my problem is:

I have Symfony2 application, I move it from localhost to development server with, but I cant run application because I geeting error:

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xx.xx.xxx.xxx' (4)' in /var/www/route/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php on line 40
```

I trying to find solution in Stackoverflow and in internet, I found that mysql has config file which blocking external resources and accept only 127.0.0.1 address, so I commented both lines as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218733/problems-in-connecting-to-mysql-server-error-2003-hy000).

My Symfony2 database parameters looks like:

```
parameters:
  database_driver: pdo_mysql
  database_host: localhost
  database_port: null
  database_name: db_name
  database_user: user
  database_password: pass
```

Can someone help to me? Thanks!

Comment: database_port: null, why is it normal?, I do not know about Symfony2 but the mysql port normal is 3306, for the other parameters you know best check that you can connect with the MySQLWorkbench

Comment: @PetterFriberg, using mysqli php extension I can connect to database and all works fine, I really cant get why this doent work with pdo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check logs in app/logs/dev.log and/or you server logs.

Are you sure that hostname an user/password combination are correct?

Where is your database? If I understood it correctly, you have your own VPS? 
If so, how you've configured it?

Probably it's not a serious issue, but we need more data.

Answer (score 0):

+1 @Mateusz Sip

You probably have a specific configuration or simply not have properly installed and configured mysql on your server.

Also you should try to do `mysql -u yourusername -p`
If it ask for your password , mysql is installed.
Enter your password and let know us if you are correctly logged in.